# how to increment google docs heading assignments while retaining relationships?

Tags: google-docs

i've got a big doc with lots of headings assigned

i'd like to select a load of text, and change all heading1 to heading2, all heading2 to heading3, etc. so that the relationships stay the same they're all just one higher (or lower)

```
eg before:
*HEADING 1
    some text

    *Heading 2
        more text

after:
*Heading 1

    *Heading 2
        some text

        *Heading3
            more text
```

basically i want to add a new category 'above' the existing text

is anything like this possible?

Comment: How method do you want to achieve your goal using?

Comment: any method which works?

Comment: From your example it is not totally clear what you want to achieve. Are you willing to use Google Apps Script? Or you are talking about the Web UI? Also, can you provide an example using Google Docs, maybe that helps to clarify. Also, how is the behavior of `Normal Text` in this context?